# how can i change dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'articles': [{'site_category': '26','tags_string': 'aaa,bbb,ccc'}, 
                     {'site_category': '43','tags_string': 'ddd,eee,fff'},
                     {'site_category': '26','tags_string': 'aaa,hhh,iii'}]}
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'articles')
print(df)

  site_category  tags_string
0            26  aaa,bbb,ccc
1            43  ddd,eee,fff
2            26  aaa,hhh,iii
```

how can i let him show this way?

```
    tags_string_list = [{"26":[{"aaa":2,"bbb":1,"ccc":1,"hhh":1,"iii":1}],
                         "43":[{'ddd': 1, 'eee': 1, 'fff': 1}],
                        }]
```

thanks for the reminder,I have corrected my expected output
thank you very much

Comment: Shouldn't the output for 26 be `{"26":[{"aaa":2,"bbb":1,"ccc":1,"hhh":1,"iii":1}`?

Comment: Where did the `hhh` go?

Comment: sorry,I lose it!
thanks for your reminder

Comment: your expected output is not a valid python code. Check the opening and closing braces

Comment: thanks for your reminder,I have corrected my expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/14627505), you can use `Counter` to transform a list of values into a dictionary that has the counts of every item of that list:

```py
from collections import Counter

result = (df['tags_string'].str.split(',')
                           .groupby(df['site_category'])
                           .agg( lambda col: dict(Counter(col.sum())) )
                           .to_dict()
)
```

`result`:

```py
{'26': {'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 1, 'ccc': 1, 'hhh': 1, 'iii': 1},
 '43': {'ddd': 1, 'eee': 1, 'fff': 1}}
```

---

If you then want to have each value of a dictionary as a single element inside a list (or whatever other format you prefer) you can use a comprehension:

```py
{k: [v] for k, v in result.items()}
```

```py
{'26': [{'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 1, 'ccc': 1, 'hhh': 1, 'iii': 1}],
 '43': [{'ddd': 1, 'eee': 1, 'fff': 1}]}
```